# unresolved socket address

Tags: java, network-programming

This is more of a novice question, but I am unable to get the type of answer I am looking for on Google.

I was reading the `InetSocketAddress` class in java.net package and I came across this method named `createUnresolved(String host, int port)`. This method creates an **unresolved** Socket.

Basically what do we mean by unresolved ? I have come across this term often in errors while compiling a program but never have understood it completely. Can anyone please explain the general meaning in java, and meaning with context to the said method.

Thanks.

Comment: It's described in the Javadoc, which you have also misquoted.

Comment: Yeah, and I also wrote that I didn't understood it completely.

Comment: Misquoting it is a big part of that. Read what it actually says.

Answer (score 1):

I found this [in a sun-blog](http://grokbase.com/t/hadoop/common-issues/117jsjk8d7/jira-created-hadoop-7472-rpc-client-should-deal-with-the-ip-address-changes):

> But decided to keep it as is but use createUnresolved() to create an
>   InetSocketAddress, so that we know what was used to instantiate it. If
>   the user slapped in an IP address to begin with, we won't handle it.
>   (I think it was indistinguishable before) The token will have whatever
>   the user used (IP or name) in the beginning and in case of using name,
>   the key to the token cache won't change even with addr changes. So the
>   delegation token should continue to work.

Basically, it's a half-baked InetSocketAddress - so it's not the final iteration. It's an intermediary step..

And From API:

> It can also be a pair (hostname + port number), in which case an
>   attempt will be made to resolve the hostname.
>
> If resolution fails then the address is said to be unresolved but can
>   still be used on some circumstances like connecting through a proxy

So we didn't find the hostname, or the user-friendly "www.abc.com" method.

But if we are connecting via a proxy it's OK because that the proxy server handles the hostname  .

Answer (score -2):

I had the same exception:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved: https://www.google.com
```

The problem was because I added the protocol `https://` 
and resolved after I removed it.

```
try {
    Socket socket = new Socket();
    socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("www.google.com", 443), 100);
    socket.close();
    return true;
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The OP didn't have this exception. Didn't have any exception.